# Guake (GTK3) started switching tabs on mouse scroll within terminal -- what causes this, where can this be (un)configured?

Tags: desktop-environment, scrolling, gtk3, user-experience

I use the [quake drop-down terminal](http://guake-project.org/) a lot.

Recently, it started to switch between tabs when I use my mouse wheel anywhere in a terminal.

Usually, I use the mouse wheel to scroll within the terminal, and *not* to switch terminal tabs. Now the behaviour ist, that it does both: It passes a scroll event to the currently opened terminal tab, and switches to the next tab, and so on, until I stop scrolling.

What might have caused this, and where can it be switched off; where is the corresponding configuration switch?

I am not sure if this is a guake issue at all or some GTK3-"magic" which was silently imposed upon me with some upgrade.

In the settings of guake (Right click -> "Preferences"), I don't see that I have mouse scroll assigned to any action, and especially under "Keyboard shortcuts", "Go to previos tab" and "Go to next tab" are assigned to `<Alt>`+`<Left>` and `<Alt>`+`<Right>`, respectively.

I am using guake version 3.9.1.dev0 (according to `guake --version`) from [Arch Linux](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/any/guake/)).

I am not using gnome, but I am using xfwm4 as window manager, without a desktop manager, and lightdm as session manager. I do start up everything I want to have ready at Xorg startup via `~/.xinitrc`.

I have already reported an issue upstream: [Here](https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/2142).

Regards!